Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write
I am using Flutter on MacOS and received this error when trying to run my Flutter app:
Error: Flutter failed to run "/Users/grc/Downloads/whizconnect-flutter-master/whizconnect-flutter-master/android/gradlew -q -Ptarget-platform=android-arm64 -Ptarget=/Users/grc/Downloads/whizconnect-flutter-master/whizconnect-flutter-master/lib/main.dart -Pbase-application-name=android.app.Application -Pdart-defines=Zmx1dHRlci5pbnNwZWN0b3Iuc3RydWN0dXJlZEVycm9ycz10cnVl,RkxVVFRFUl9XRUJfQ0FOVkFTS0lUX1VSTD1odHRwczovL3d3dy5nc3RhdGljLmNvbS9mbHV0dGVyLWNhbnZhc2tpdC9lZGQ4NTQ2MTE2NDU3YmRmMWM1YmRmYjEzZWNiOTQ2M2QyYmI1ZWQ0Lw== -Pdart-obfuscation=false -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=false -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root assembleDebug".
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.


The error indicates that you haven't installed Flutter properly. Follow the documentation and install it correctly: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos/desktop?tab=download#install-the-flutter-sdk
Also try to give your user permissions to the directory that you installed flutter in:
sudo chmod u+rwx /Path/to/flutter/sdk


First, ensure that Flutter SDK is correctly installed and configured on your system:
Open Terminal and run flutter doctor. This command checks your Flutter installation and reports any issues.
Second, ensure your project directory (/Users/grc/Downloads/whizconnect-flutter-master/whizconnect-flutter-master) has "Read & Write" permissions for your user:
Step 1: Navigate to your project directory (/Users/grc/Downloads/whizconnect-flutter-master/whizconnect-flutter-master) in Finder.
Step 2: Right-click on the project folder, select "Get Info," and ensure your user account has "Read & Write" permissions under the "Sharing & Permissions" section.
Lastly, run flutter clean, flutter pub get, and then try flutter run again to rebuild the project
